# No data from rest call

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am simply wanting to return data from a url localhost:8080/rest/items. Below is the ember code but it does seem to return or make a call to get any data;

```
       App = Ember.Application.create({

});

var attr = DS.attr;

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    name : attr(),
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
      revision: 12,
      adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
    });

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
      revision: 12,
      adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        url: 'rest'
      })
    });

App.ItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function () {
        App.Item.find();
      }
});
```

I am new to ember and do not know what is incorrect with this code.

Comment: Are you serving the web page with this js up on a local server? P&B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch to a newer version of ember data (http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.0.0-beta.3/ember-data.js), and do it like this

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  namespace: 'rest'
});

App = Ember.Application.create({});

var attr = DS.attr;

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    name : attr(),
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter;

App.ItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function () {
        this.store.find('item');
      }
});
```

Comment: thank you, I must be missing something key how is this being called, I added your code and check the network and no call is made to my restful api, Am I missing the 'App.Router.map' and if so how do you use it?

Comment: Are you hitting the item route?

Comment: I added 'App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('items', {
        path: '/'
    });
}); this solved the problem but does this make sense?

Comment: sure if you want items to be the resource that lives at the root of your application :)